# Dillinger.io markdown editor: how do I recover my text?

Tags: github, editor, markdown

I linked Dillinger.io to my Github account.

Then I typed a ton of text in Dillinger.io

While I was typing, it kept saying "saved locally".

I closed the browser.

Now I go to dillinger.io 30 mins later and my text is gone. It also doesn't seem to be on Github.

Where's my text? Somewhere in Github? Somewhere in the Dillinger.io UI? Or can I find it by inspecting my HTML5 LocalStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Dillinger.io saves its text in browser Local Storage.

The key is `profile`. The value is JSON encoded object, where text is `currentMd` property.